# mongodb filter array of nested documents

Tags: mongodb-query

I want to find one and filter profile like that by `moduleId` and `name`

```
 {
    "moduleId": 1,
    "access": {
      "del": ..,
      "editWrite": ...,
      "read": ....
    }
  }
```

the document looks like this:

```
    "profileAccess": [
      {
        "moduleId": 1,
        "access": {
          "del": true,
          "editWrite": true,
          "read": true
        }
      },
      {
        "moduleId": 2,
        "access": {
          "del": true,
          "editWrite": true,
          "read": true
        }
      }
      
    ],
    "name": "admin"
   },
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: found the answer it seems i forget to return the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer it seems i forget to return the response

```
Profile.findOne({name:"admin"},{profileAccess: { $elemMatch: { moduleId: 1} }});
```